# How to reset an instrument configuration in Hydrogen?

Tags: software, hydrogen

I haven't found a way to reset an instrument configuration back to the default. I'm referring to this menu:

[image: screenshot]

[the software manual](http://hydrogen-music.org/documentation/manual/manual_en.html)